# can I use <br> tags inside <em> tag

Tags: html, syntax, tags

Can I use the following syntax in HTML5?

```
<p><em>If this is a poem<br>
  can I close the <br> tags<br>
  of each verse,<br>
  in a single &lt;em&gt; tag<br>
  as I in this example do?</em></p>
```

Comment: Yes, You can do that.

Comment: You can, but given your poem example here I'd question the use of em more than the use of br...

Comment: One of your `<em>` tags isn't closed. Also, when it comes to syntactic validity of your HTML, you can always run a page through the [W3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: I would probably use css instead of <em> tags in this situation (font-style: italic;)

Comment: @j08691 you've right. I just edited the second <em>. It's there as text, not tag.

Comment: @Maverick976 very good approach. I'll follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

what you have works, however its kind of sloppy. I would take this approach. Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/hvsas2Lj/

I styled everything in the `css` and took out all the `<br>` tags

Comment: `br` elements actually make sense for poems and along with addresses are one of the handful of valid uses: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

Comment: What "makes sense" in this question is highly opinionated, I would never build a site like that, however, if you choose to and it work well for you, go for it. I personally like having clean and easy html to modify.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a  pre element it defines preformatted text and it preserves both spaces and line breaks.

```
<pre>
if this is a poem<br>
  can I close the <br> tags<br>
  of each verse,<br>
  in a single &lt;em&gt; tag<br>
  as I in this example do?</em>
</pre>
```